# 50 questions / 30 days limit with only 2 questions posted

Tags: support, asking-questions, monthly-question-limit

I have only asked 2 questions ever; when I now try to ask a question, it says that I have exceeeded the limit of 50 questions/30 days.  What's going on? How can I fix it?

Comment: do you have any fake account?

Comment: I don't know what a fake account is.  I just use this account in the regular stackoverflow.

Comment: Are you using a corporate, or shared, IP address?

Comment: maybe people in your office or workplace sharing the same IP..

Comment: Are you behind a nat?=

Comment: hmm yeah that'd make sense. I guess the limit then is per-IP , not per-account.

Comment: indeed, to block people opening new accounts.

Comment: So... is there any solution for him? Can the limit be reset manually?

Comment: There are other people using the same IP as you to access Stack Overflow. A *lot* of other people. Like... Way more than I can count. You should give them a piece of your mind...

Answer (score 30, accepted):

For very low reputation accounts, this is indeed enforced at both the IP and account level. This means other people sharing your IP address (coworkers, fellow university students or just other people using your ISP) might have already used up a large amount of the questions-per-time period allowance.

I found your existing two questions to be of high quality and worthy of upvotes, so you might wish to try asking again.

(and don't forget we have http://tex.stackexchange.com and http://stats.stackexchange.com as well..)

Comment: How low does rep have to be for this?

Comment: @quant 125 avoids IP blocks.

Comment: As carrier-grade NAT continues to force several users onto one IPv4 address, what is the workaround? Must all new users suggest 62 edits first?