# Reached 50-questions limit with only 6 questions?

Tags: support, monthly-question-limit

I am receiving following error while posting a question:

> Sorry, you are only allowed to ask 50 questions in a 30 day period.

I have posted only 6 questions in last 5-6 months. May I know what is the reason behind it and how to get read of it?

Comment: Where are you asking these questions from? Are you behind a corporate firewall? Are other people using the same IP also asking questions?

Comment: It looks like all of your outbound traffic at the office is coming from a single IP, unfortunately that means we can't distinguish the machines (or users creating dupe accounts to ask)...it's an IP throttle you're seeing.

Comment: Yeah it seems it was the issue because of IP only. I tried posting the question using my Mobile Internet (instead of Office Network)and it worked!

Comment: @chown It's not a bug; it's intended that way to prevent people from simply logging out of their account to get more questions.

Comment: @AndrewBarber: "feature"

Comment: Shouldn't this feature be based on per user account rather than IP address? Rather a combination of both userID and IP ;)

Comment: This will become a bigger problem over time. Is there a better solution?

Answer (score 0):

As explained by Jeff in [50 questions / 30 days limit with only 2 questions posted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/93738/50-questions-30-days-limit-with-only-2-questions-posted/93772#93772):

> For very low reputation accounts, this is indeed enforced at both the IP and account level.