# I haven't asked more than 50 questions in 30 days, but SO thinks I did

Tags: support

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [50 questions / 30 days limit with only 2 questions posted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/93738/50-questions-30-days-limit-with-only-2-questions-posted)

I haven't asked 50 questions in 30 days, but when I went to ask a question a few minutes ago, it gave me that error. I go to school where students share the same IP. Maybe other students are asking on SO? Is this why I got the error?

Comment: Yes, that is why. See the answer to the question I've linked above.