# Submission of question denied

Tags: support, bug

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [50 questions / 30 days limit with only 2 questions posted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/93738/50-questions-30-days-limit-with-only-2-questions-posted)

I recently joined StackOverflow and I have posted just 3 queries till now. Today when I am trying to post another question, I get the following error msg:

```
Oops! Your question couldn't be submitted because:

Sorry, you are only allowed to ask 50 questions in a 30 day period
```

I never crossed even 10! Why am I getting this error msg?

Comment: Possibly related to [Post limit error when not even close to the limit](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/98696)

Comment: In other words, it may be that you share an IP address.

Comment: Yeah, looks like your IP is shared by a few different accounts.