# New user can't post question

Tags: support, math-se

I'm a new user here, and I wanted to post a question in Math.SE, but whenever I try to post a question I get a message saying I can only post 50 question in 30 day period. But, I haven't even started posting.

Comment: There's probably other people on the same ip address.

Comment: @Mysticial Yes, in fact there a few people using the site too. It's a public place.

Comment: You can try to use a [proxy server](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proxy_list)

Comment: [50 questions / 30 days limit with only 2 questions posted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/93772)