# "You can only post once every 40 minutes" on my first post

Tags: bug, asking-questions, rate-limiting

I have never posted on the [Monero Stack Exchange site](https://monero.stackexchange.com/tour) yet.

I just wrote my first question, but when I click "**Post Your Question**", I get "**You can only post once every 40 minutes.**"

I haven't posted any question today on any Stack Exchange site.

I tried to report this on the [Monero meta site](https://monero.meta.stackexchange.com/), but I got the same issue.

Let's try here...

Comment: Well at least it worked here :) I was going to say, it sucks that reporting bugs involves going through that same bug ...

Comment: I am inside my work office, with hundreds of employees. Although ... this never happened in the years before, and it's a tech company so I bet people use StackExchange a lot...

Comment: oh, my Monero post just went through now.

Comment: @gnat: No, that's dealing with *one's own* earlier question preventing a new question. While the same mechanism is of course in play, the explanation needs to include IP address sharing as well, which Journeyman Geek's answer here does, but none of the linked dupe chains does.

Comment: @NathanTuggy IP level restrictions are explained in another question: [50 questions / 30 days limit with only 2 questions posted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/93772/165773)

Comment: @gnat: Then maybe perhaps just possibly you should have dupe-flagged *that one* instead? (Still not ideal, but at least it ties together two seemingly different messages with the same cause, rather than requiring mindreading to tell how the answer even applies.)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Bit of guesswork here

> Users with < 125 rep, 40 minutes since their last question anywhere on
>   the network (This applies to the user's IP address, not their account.
>   If the user shares that IP with other users, they can be limited by
>   the other user asking a question anywhere on the network.)

<sub>[source - The Complete Rate Limiting Guide](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/164899/the-complete-rate-limiting-guide)</sub>

You have more than 125 rep here - so no rate limits here or on *most* of the sites you're on. you have 101 on monero

On other sites? I guess someone you share an IP with posted *somewhere on the network* within the last 40 minutes.

Comment: Wow, that's pretty broken. What with a rapidly increasing number of people getting put under CGN, and places that previously used to give everyone their own IP now going behind a single gateway IP (like companies and university dorms), I don't think it makes any sense to filter/block people by IP anymore. IP no longer refers to a *user*; it's practically useless as a tool to determine who's on the other end of the wire.

Comment: I suspect this is one of those things that bites new users more (since the amount of reputation needed is semi trivial), but it'll need a little work for a compelling feature request to undo it. I think we'd need *graphs* or something ;p

Comment: .... https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/322157/arent-new-users-throttled-asking-questions-anymore/322265#322265 related post. With graphs...

Comment: @allquixotic What do you propose using instead to prevent spammers and abusive users from trivially getting around rate limits and blocks by creating new accounts?

Comment: well, in theory 125 rep *on any one account* might work. Its one of those issues that's probably less serious now, and even less so in the past, than it might be in the future.

Comment: I agree that considering I have high reputation on several other SE sites, it should have a weight in the algorithm no?

Comment: actually - that feels like it would make a lot of sense.

Comment: I have 12K on math.se and just got hit with the 40 minute rule on islam.se. I think this is a little nonsensical of a rule.

Comment: At least if ONE account has reached past 500 rep you can expect they will try to do a good job on other sites.

Comment: Sorry for the necro, but is this still broken this way? I am unable to post questions on relevant sites because of this error message. Initially I thought it was because the site first prompts me to review my question, before I can actually post. And yes, I consider this broken if I'm logged in, the site should distinguish me from other users on the same IP address. I guess this is to prevent shadow accounts, but then the rep suggestion above would've saved me (384K on SO) if it were implemented. But I guess not.

Comment: As far as I understand it's still the case.